# Улучшение нейросети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

У меня есть датасет который состоит из 11 колонок и 8640 строк. Я построил нейросеть который состоит из 3 inputs С двумя hidden layers и 1 output. Вообще по идее 8 output но нужно для каждого output отдельный модель. И для этого я использовал функцию. Test set 33% Traning set 67%.

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    inputs= Inputs_arr
    outputs= Outputs_arr[:, i].reshape(-1, 1)
    
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    inputs=sc.fit_transform(inputs)
    outputs=sc.fit_transform(outputs)
    
    condition = np.isin(Inputs_arr[:,1], (8, 2))
    inputs_train, inputs_test = inputs[~condition], inputs[condition]
    outputs_train, outputs_test = outputs[~condition], outputs[condition]
    
    
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    model = Sequential([
      layers.Dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 3),
      layers.Dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu'),
      layers.Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.09))
    ])
    
    opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer =opt, loss='mse')
    history = model.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train, validation_data=(inputs_test, outputs_test), epochs=100, batch_size=65)
```

теперь данный момент R^2 равен 0.87, Training Mean Squared Error 0.0749
Test Mean Squared Error 0.1236. Как можно улучить модель?

Comment: Модель видимо переобучается. Попробуйте увеличить learning rate, уменьшить число элементов в скрытых слоях. Хотя скор и так хороший с виду, куда лучше то.

Comment: Почему каждый раз результат меняется? То есть одна и та же модель но результат разный

Comment: Использовать кросс-валидацию при обучении и оценке. Объявить kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform() и такой же bias_initializer в полносвязных слоях. Вероятно для ваших данных может быть слишком большой batch_size.

Comment: @Andrew А как это реализовать я уменшил батчсайз на 60, А это не смог сделать kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform() и такой же bias_initializer

Comment: layers.Dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 3, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(), bias_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform())
Также добавь Dropout между полносвязными слоями. Поэкспериментируй с rate у Dropout от 0.1 до 0.6

Comment: @ Andrew  Результат улучшился но как только я обновил и снова запустил код результат изменился в худшую сторону! почему обучение каждый раз дает разные результаты? Training Mean Absolute Error 0.08444403540865811
Test Mean Absolute Error 0.09825211770524227
Training Mean Squared Error 0.06562827111684527
Test Mean Squared Error 0.06892866944175058
Test R2 0.9304792888793281
Train R2 0.9301825143984431

Comment: И возможно ли каким-то способом уменьшиться значение МSЕ